# Bootstrap formatting issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, formatting

I am building a form using Bootstrap, and I have a spacing issue that I cannot resolve.

Here is my code:

```
<row>
  <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-12 margin-bottom-5">
    <label class="col-md-4">24 Months</label>
    <input type="text" readonly name="sum-lease24-mpp" class="sum-24mpp col-md-2" id="sum-lease24-mpp"><br />
    <input type="text" readonly name="sum-lease24-tpm" class="sum-24tpm col-md-2 margin-left-5" id="sum-lease24-tpm"><br />
  </div>
</row>
```

Here is what the row looks like:

[image: Screenshot of appearance]

As you can see the second text input field is bumped slightly down. Can someone tell why this is happening and how to fix it please?

Comment: The problem is these br tags in your code. If you want to break line then use a bootstrap form.

Comment: Ah now I just feel foolish. I copied these over from another page I was using and didn't remove the break tags. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <row>
        <div class="form-group col-md-offset-1 col-md-12 margin-bottom-5">
            <div class="control-label col-md-2">
                <label>24 Months</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="sum-lease24-mpp" class="form-control sum-24mpp" id="sum-lease24-mpp">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="sum-lease24-tpm" class="form-control sum-24tpm col-md-4 margin-left-5" id="sum-lease24-tpm">
            </div>
        </div>
    </row>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Bootstrap 3. I'm assuming you meant `<div class="row">` and not `<row>`.

Normally you use `form-inline` to get Bootstrap to keep the form on the same line, and then wrap each group of label/input with `form-group`. (See [Inline form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)) However, if you need grid-based sizing, it doesn't really work right with form-inline.

You can still use grid for this but you need to wrap each element in a `<div class="col-xx-xx">`
(See [Control sizing](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes))

Each form element needs to be tagged with `form-control` too, or Bootstrap will format it quite strangely.

```
<div class="row margin-bottom-5"> <!-- assuming margin-bottom-5 defined in CSS -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
        <!-- This isn't really a label for a single form element, is it? -->
        <b>24 Months</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <!-- A label is expected for each form element. Use sr-only to hide it  -->
        <label for="sum-lease24-mpp" class="sr-only">Sum 24 MPP</label>
        <input type="text" readonly name="sum-lease24-mpp" class="form-control sum-24mpp" id="sum-lease24-mpp">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 margin-left-5">
        <label for="sum-lease24-tpm" class="sr-only">Sum 24 TPM</label>
        <input type="text" readonly name="sum-lease24-tpm" class="form-control sum-24tpm" id="sum-lease24-tpm">
    </div>
</div>
```